# Passing a variable to a closure that is executed as a callable

Tags: groovy, closures

In Groovy we can do this...

```
def pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)
def defer = { c -> pool.submit(c as Callable) }   

def myfunction = {"hello"}
def deferedInvocation = defer(myfunction)

def response = deferedInvocation.get() 
println response    // outputs hello
```

What I'd like to do is for the defer closure to pass one its closed variables into the closure c it invokes.

So we have an outervariable `tony`

Something like this:

```
def tony = "tony"
def pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)
def defer = { c -> pool.submit(c(tony) as Callable) }   // tony is closed variable

def myfunction = {"hello " + it}
def deferedInvocation = defer(myfunction)

def response = deferedInvocation.get() 
println response
```

However, when I try that I get:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MissingMethodExceptionNoStack: No signature of method: java.lang.String.call() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: wait(), any(), wait(long), each(groovy.lang.Closure), any(groovy.lang.Closure), take(int)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce your example, but seems like the `as Callable` part is already executed, and the resulting `"hello" + it` is being submitted to the pool

Try encapsulating the `Callable` in a closure to really defer execution:

```
def defer = { c -> pool.submit({ c(tony) } as Callable) }
```